# Looking for two Greek passengers who probably arrived in New York in 1923

Tags: united-states, immigration, new-york-city, greece

I'm trying to locate the following family (both Greek) on the passenger lists:

- George (Georgios) Vogiatzis
- Charalampos Vogiatzis

Must have arrived in New York probably in 1923 after the [Minor Asia catastrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_Asia_Catastrophe) (Greek: Μικρασιατική Καταστροφή).

Comment: What information do you already have (such as ages), and where have you already searched?  For example, if the family is present in the 1930 census, are they also present in 1920 or 1910?  This extra information could give you a clue as to whether the Charalampos Vogiatzis who arrived in 1909 (https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/JXBC-WNG ) is correct, or maybe a different generation (or unrelated).  Same for Georgios, lots of them arriving in various years (1910,11,15,16 etc) so you'd need more background to narrow it down.  You can edit your question with any extra information you have.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the Greeks who came to the US at that time primarily entered through the Port of New York?  There are many other possible ports of entry, all of which were in operation in the 1920s.  For search forms and more information see Stephen P. Morse's One-Step Web pages at http://stevemorse.org/

Comment: The 1909 manifest Rob Hoare found for Charalampos gives a birthplace of Istanbul, Turkey.  This record is a good candidate for someone whose family would have been expelled in 1923.  We need more information to discover whether this is the right Charalampos or someone else with the same name.  Many immigrant families went back and forth several times before remaining in the US, and some manifests will tell you whether the person has been in the US before and for how long.  All of these plus the names of relatives and friends can be valuable clues.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Vogiatzis     Charalampos that arrived in NY from Smyrna, Smyrna, Turkey A.    at the age of      36y    (born 1872-1873 ) on    June 3rd 1909   on the ship Athinai . It's a bit earlier then 1923 though. You do not say whether Charalampos and George arrived at the same time.

Info : Passenger ID 101613020237